# Why is my List falling out of scope in a WCF post?

Tags: c#, wcf

I've been investigating RESTful webservices hosted via a console application to solve a specific use case (ASP.NET is overkill for our current needs) and I am a bit confused.

First off I created a WCF webservice by following these [MSDN directions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb412178%28v=vs.100%29.aspx). This works well, I am able to issue GET and POST requests and get a response.

Looking to extend this example to our use case I need to save the POST data into a collection:

so I changed the original post code from:

```
public string EchoWithPost(string s)
{
    return "You said " + s;
}
```

to

```
 public List<string> Bc = new List<string>();
 public string EchoWithPost(string s)
    {
        this.Bc.Add(s);
        return "You said " + s;
    }
```

Expecting my list to grow with each new POST request. This is not the case however. By watching the debugger I determined that each new POST request instantiated a new list causing the old list to fall out of scope and to be lost.

Why is this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your WCF service is created as a new instance with each request that it handles. There are multiple things you can do, depending on your needs.

- Change your list instance to a static variable (not recommended).
- Change your instance-context-mode to a single instance. This means that all your wcf requests are handled by a single instance. The downside is that your service can only handle one request at a time. See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.servicebehaviorattribute.instancecontextmode.aspx). Not recommended either if you need to handle multiple requests simultanously.
- Change your instance-context-mode to per-session. Basically an instance of your service is created for each client.

I suspect the third option is most suitable to your needs.

Comment: Why is static not recommended?

Comment: @RobertH for the same reason the 2nd option is not recommended, you can only support one client at a time as two concurrent users requests would fight for who was the "last" request.

Comment: @RobertH In general I consider it a red flag for a design issue.

Comment: You could also use a ObjectCache, to store the entries over multiple requests.

Answer (score 0):

Because a new instance of your service is created every time you perform a new call.

You should use a static list or use another type of persistence.

```
public static List<string> Bc = new List<string>();
public string EchoWithPost(string s)
{
    this.Bc.Add(s);
    return "You said " + s;
}
```